# Display Date Specific URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Objective is to show a link on the page based on a date

Since I am very new to JS, would there be a more efficient way to achieve this?

The below code works but ideally I would like to edit the HTML and not JS every time I want a change i.e enter dates and URL in HTML file and not the JS.

Links and dates are currently added manually in the JS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="ademo"></p>

<script>
  var yr = new Date().getFullYear();
  var mn = new Date().getMonth()+1;
  var dt = new Date().getDate();    

  var showlink;
  var showlink1 = ('<a href="http://#">URL-1</a>');
  var showlink2 = ('<a href="http://#">URL-2</a>');
  var showlink3 = ('<a href="http://#">URL-3</a>');
  var showlink4 = ('<a href="http://#">URL-4</a>');

  if (yr == 2021 && mn == 3 && dt == 15) {
    showlink = showlink1; 

  } else if (yr == 2021 && mn == 3 && dt == 16) {
    showlink = showlink2;

  } else if (yr == 2021 && mn == 3 && dt == 17) {
    showlink = showlink3;

  } else if (yr == 2021 && mn == 3 && dt == 18) {
    showlink = showlink4;
  }

  document.getElementById("ademo").innerHTML = showlink.toString();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using any jQuery (which is fine).

Comment: Open to using jquery if needed - tagged since I have asked for suggestion to improve the code.

Comment: To be able to help you here we need to understand how you generate the links. There seems to be no system at place other than incrementing the link text.

Comment: Links are currently added manually in the JS

Comment: And what link is displayed based on what date?

Comment: Links as variables showlink1 / Dates defined as variables yr,mn,dt. Result = URL1 will be displayed on 15th March 2021 and URL2 will be displayed on 16th March 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by adding a data object and manage that. This could also be an external JSON file you include in your code.

Adding your data into HTML will just bloat your HTML and likely have accessibility issues you need to deal with.

```js
const data = {
    '2021-3-15': '<a href="http://#">URL-1</a>',
    '2021-3-16': '<a href="http://#">URL-2</a>',
    '2021-3-17': '<a href="http://#">URL-3</a>',
    '2021-3-18': '<a href="http://#">URL-4</a>',
};

const year = new Date().getFullYear();
const month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
const day = new Date().getDate();
const key = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;

document.getElementById("ademo").innerHTML = data[key];
```

```html
<p id="ademo"></p>
```

And if you want to us an external JSON file you'd do it this way:

```js
async function loadData() {
    const rawJson = await fetch('/url/to/your/data.json');
    const data = await rawJson.json();

    const year = new Date().getFullYear();
    const month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    const day = new Date().getDate();
    const key = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;

    document.getElementById("ademo").innerHTML = data[key];
}

loadData();
```

While your JSON would be in this shape:

```json
{
    "2021-3-15": "<a href=\"http://#\">URL-1</a>",
    "2021-3-16": "<a href=\"http://#\">URL-2</a>",
    "2021-3-17": "<a href=\"http://#\">URL-3</a>",
    "2021-3-18": "<a href=\"http://#\">URL-4</a>"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, external JSON sounds exciting, could you pls provide a working example for me to follow.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include an example. Make sure you know what browsers you're supporting and adjust your code accordingly. In case you want to use jQuery because you have to support old browsers, you'd likely want to use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: Thanks, I believe the const data would no longer be required in the JS as seen above

Comment: thanks and sorry that I may be expanding here a little bit but if you can, how would I achieve displaying a link between dates i.e. from 1st to 15th March? possible?

Comment: That's the bit I was asking about in the comments earlier. What is the system behind what links go with what dates. If ranges are a thing that changes everything and probably means you want to shape your data differently. Maybe worth opening a new question for this.

Comment: My objective should be achieved with what you have stated, just looking to extend functionality.

Comment: Returns "Undefined" when used with JSON

Comment: the JS only works ok but the JSON example return Undefined in the final HTML result, could you pls assist @Dominik

Comment: You have to make sure the JSON is hosted next to your js and accessible.

Comment: Unable to make it work, see  https://pentatechnology.com/ademo/ademo.html all files next to each other (ademo.html, ademo.js,ademo.json) chrome devtools reports nothing @Dominik

Comment: Please open a new question for your problem. In your linked code you're using `await fetch('ademo.json');` but should use `await fetch('https://pentatechnology.com/ademo/ademo.json');`

Comment: And don't put your script in the header or it will try to find the `getElementById("ademo")` which hasn't loaded yet. Add it at the very bottom of body or put your function inside a [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) callback

Comment: Thanks, done all of that and the result is the same, have modified now and no luck, thx

Comment: Resolved with await rawJson.json(); instead of just rawJson.json() as answered by @Lakshya Thakur at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66688321/json-js-returns-undefined

Comment: ++ and @deceze at stackoverflow.com/questions/66688321/json-js-returns-undefined